# Suspend activity in Android Studio

Tags: android

How can an activity be suspended in Android studio?

I need to test which states are reached when an activity is suspended. I tried doing `this.finish()` on an activity and the `onPause()`, `onStop()`, and `onDestroy()` were called however, I'm not sure whether I tested this well using `this.finish()` since I also need to test the states reached when an activity is exited by the user and I'm mixed up whether both can be tested using `this.finish()`.

Comment: what you mean by suspended? An activity is either on the screen (onResumed) or paused (onPause). There is no suspend and no other state that i know of

Answer (score 0):

maybe  you can override the methods of the onPause(),onStop(),onDestroy() and write some log coment like a sout or log to check

when you call the onDestroy , you go through this life cycle except for the finish() method
http://developer.android.com/images/training/basics/basic-lifecycle-create.png

here you can check the order of the calls.

Note: The system calls onDestroy() after it has already called onPause() and onStop() in all situations except one: when you call finish() from within the onCreate() method. In some cases, such as when your activity operates as a temporary decision maker to launch another activity, you might call finish() from within onCreate() to destroy the activity. In this case, the system immediately calls onDestroy() without calling any of the other lifecycle methods.

from here you can get all the lyfeCycle information Hope it helps you

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html